# Is there any way to implement toast message in xamarin forms without custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

So far I have been using `dependency service` for displaying `toast messages` in `Xamarin.Forms`.

Now I am looking for a way where I can develop `toast message` in `Xamarin Cross platform` only without using `Custom renderer` and `dependency service`.

Can anyone suggest me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the ACR User Dialogs nugget plugin.

https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

I am using it for all my projects !

Quick example

```
Acr.UserDialogs.ToastConfig.DefaultPosition = ToastPosition.Top;

Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.InfoToast("Toast at the top");
```

Comment: Is there anything we can do without plugin

Comment: Only with dependency services if you don't want to use a third party plugin. I recommend the user dialogs, it is a life saver and it has a very beautiful loaders also!!

Comment: create your own controltemplate and place a text using absolutelayout and run a timer function which does visibility off and on, after this use the control template on your contentpages and now you have all the control over your customer toaster

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something on the new https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Sample.Pages"
                x:Class="Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Sample.Pages.Views.SnackBarPage">
    <StackLayout Spacing="10" Margin="20">
        <Button Clicked="DisplaySnackBarClicked" Text="Show SnackBar"></Button>
        <Button Clicked="DisplayToastClicked" Text="Show toast"></Button>
        <Button Clicked="DisplaySnackBarAdvancedClicked" Text="Show SnackBar"></Button>
        <Label x:Name="StatusText"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:BasePage>




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Extensions;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.Options;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Sample.Pages.Views
{
    public partial class SnackBarPage : BasePage
    {
        public SnackBarPage() => InitializeComponent();

        async void DisplaySnackBarClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var result = await this.DisplaySnackBarAsync(GenerateLongText(5), "Run action", () =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("SnackBar action button clicked");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
            StatusText.Text = result ? "SnackBar is closed by user" : "SnackBar is closed by timeout";
        }

        async void DisplayToastClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var result = await this.DisplayToastAsync(GenerateLongText(5));
            StatusText.Text = result ? "SnackBar is closed by user" : "SnackBar is closed by timeout";
        }

        async void DisplaySnackBarAdvancedClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var messageOptions = new MessageOptions
            {
                Foreground = Color.DeepSkyBlue,
                FontSize = 40,
                FontFamily = "Sans-serif",
                Message = GenerateLongText(5)
            };

            var actionOptions = new List<SnackBarActionOptions>
            {
                new SnackBarActionOptions
                {
                    ForegroundColor = Color.Red,
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
                    FontSize = 40,
                    FontFamily = "Sans-serif",
                    Text = "Action1",
                    Action = () =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("1");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                },
                new SnackBarActionOptions
                {
                    ForegroundColor = Color.Green,
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                    FontSize = 20,
                    FontFamily = "Sans-serif",
                    Text = "Action2",
                    Action = () =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("2");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                }
            };
            var options = new SnackBarOptions(messageOptions, 5000, Color.Coral, true, actionOptions);
            var result = await this.DisplaySnackBarAsync(options);
            StatusText.Text = result ? "SnackBar is closed by user" : "SnackBar is closed by timeout";
        }

        string GenerateLongText(int stringDuplicationTimes)
        {
            const string message = "It is a very long message to test multiple strings. A B C D E F G H I I J K LO P Q R S T U V W X Y Z";
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            for (var i = 0; i < stringDuplicationTimes; i++)
            {
                result.AppendLine(message);
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```